# Linq select list from ObservableCollection with different models in WPF

Tags: c#, json, linq, mvvm

**Scenario:** I have two Datagrid which bind to `ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList` and `ObservableCollection<ProductQuantity> QuantityList`. I would like to select and add `List<ProductQuantity> Stock` from `ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList` where ProductList.id == SelectedProduct.id to new `ObservableCollection<ProductQuantity> QuantityList`. So whenever user select a row from ProductList, QuantityList will be updated based on the select row.

**Model (Product.cs)**

```
public class Product : ObservableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Product_no { get; set; }

    public List<ProductQuantity> Stock { get; set; }
}

public class ProductQuantity : ObservableObject
{
    public string Branch_name { get; set; }

    public float Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel (ProductViewModel.cs)**

```
public class ProductViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ProductViewModel()
    {
        searchCommand = new RelayCommand(Search);

        SelectedProduct = new Product();
    }

    #region Define
    private ObservableCollection<Product> productList;
    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList
    {
        get { return productList; }
        set { productList = value; OnPropertyChanged("ProductList"); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ProductQuantity> quantityList;
    public ObservableCollection<ProductQuantity> QuantityList
    {
        get { return quantityList; }
        set { quantityList = value; OnPropertyChanged("QuantityList"); }
    }

    private Product selectedProduct;
    public Product SelectedProduct
    {
        get { return selectedProduct; }
        set
        { 
            selectedProduct = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProduct");
            LoadProductQuantity();
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #region CustomOperation
    private void LoadProductQuantity()
    {
        if (ProductList != null)
        {
            // here
            QuantityList = new ObservableCollection<ProductQuantity>((List<ProductQuantity>)ProductList.Where(e => e.Id == SelectedProduct.Id).Select(s => s.Stock));
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #region SearchOperation
    private RelayCommand searchCommand;
    public RelayCommand SearchCommand
    {
        get { return searchCommand; }
    }
    private async void Search()
    {
        try
        {
            
            RootProductObject Response = await GetProductListAPI();
                

            //datagrid
            ProductList = new ObservableCollection<Product>(Response.Data.OrderBy(property => property.Id));
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

**Json from backend API (express.js)**

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "product_no": "a000001",
        "stock": [
            {
                "branch_name": "US Branch",
                "quantity": 3.1
            },
            {
                "branch_name": "India Branch",
                "quantity": 3.1
            },
            {
                "branch_name": "Russia Branch",
                "quantity": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "product_no": "a000003",
        "stock": [
            {
                "branch_name": "US Branch",
                "quantity": 3.9
            },
            {
                "branch_name": "India Branch",
                "quantity": 3.2
            },
            {
                "branch_name": "Russia Branch",
                "quantity": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

> Error: Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in MyProject.dll. 
> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in MyProject.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
>  Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[MyProject.Models.Product,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProject.Models.ProductQuantity]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProject.Models.ProductQuantity]'.

Comment: Where do you you get the exception? Can you show the code pls?

Comment: remove typecast `(List<ProductQuantity>)` from `(List<ProductQuantity>)ProductList.Where(e => e.Id == SelectedProduct.Id).Select(s => s.Stock)`. ObservableCollection has constructor overload with IEnumerable

Comment: @Sergey I get the exception at the line of code after the comment (// here) at ViewModel

Comment: @ASh After I remove the typecast, I am getting this error : 
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProject.Models.ProductQuantity>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.ProductQuantity>' MyProject C:\Projects\MyProject\ViewModels\ProductViewModel.cs 92 Active

Comment: @Chris Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void LoadProductQuantity()
{
    if (ProductList != null)
    {
        var product = ProductList.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == SelectedProduct.Id);
        if (product != null)
            QuantityList = new ObservableCollection<ProductQuantity>(product.Stock);
        else
            QuantityList = new ObservableCollection<ProductQuantity>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say this is the exact answer that could fully solve my problem, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
 QuantityList = new ObservableCollection<ProductQuantity>
( 
ProductList.Where(e => e.Id == SelectedProduct.Id)
.Select(s => s.Stock)
.FirstOrDefault()
);
```

Comment: This code works for me also, but @ASh 's answer suits my use cases the most. Anyway thanks for your help as well !!